# COMO PUEDO ELIMINAR EL WIDGET "ENTRY" DESPUES DE HABER INTRODUCIDO UN VALOR EN EL MISMO?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

QUIERO DESTRUIR EL WIDGET "ENTRY" UNA VEZ QUE HAYA SIDO UTILIZADO PARA QUE YA NO ESTE PRESENTE.
EL BLOQUEARLO O DESHABILITARLO NO ME RESULTA UTIL =(

Comment: `entry.destroy()` te sirve?

Comment: Además, te recomiendo evitar el uso excesivo de mayusculas, das la impresión de estar gritando...

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, no uses mayúsculas sostenidas ,que se lee a gritos y sé que no es la idea. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).